Warning about rank transformation not taking weights into account in coin::kruskal_test in R
I'm using the coin::kruskal_test function in R to perform a weighted Kruskal-Wallis test, but I'm encountering a warning that the rank transformation doesn't take weights into account.
Here's the code that produces the warning:
library(tidyverse)
library(coin)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1)
punteggi = 
  tibble(
    Codice = paste0("cod_", 1:200),
    Regione = sample(c("FVG", "Lazio", "Sicilia"), size = 200, replace = T, prob = c(.4, .2, .4)),
    Genere = sample(c("Femminile", "Maschile"), size = 200, replace = T, prob = c(.6, .4)),
    Area = sample(c("Urbana", "Extra urbana"), size = 200, replace = T, prob = c(.6, .4)),
  )



punteggi = punteggi |> 
  group_by(Regione, Genere, Area) |> 
  mutate(
    mu = runif(1, 4, 7),
    sd = runif(1, 1, 2),
    weight = n()
  ) |> 
  ungroup() |>
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(pt_tot = rnorm(1, mu, sd))

punteggi

kruskal_per_group_weighted <- function(data) {
  test_result <- tryCatch({
      coin::kruskal_test(pt_tot ~ value, data = data, weights = ~ weight)
  }, error = function(e) {
    message("Errore in kruskal_test: ", e)
    return(NULL)
  })
  return(coin::pvalue(test_result))
}

kruskal_per_group_NO_weighted <- function(data) {
  test_result <- tryCatch({
      coin::kruskal_test(pt_tot ~ value, data = data)
  }, error = function(e) {
    message("Errore in kruskal_test: ", e)
    return(NULL)
  })
  return(coin::pvalue(test_result))
}

punteggi |> 
  pivot_longer(c(Regione, Genere, Area)) |> 
  mutate(across(value, as.factor)) |> 
  nest(.by = name) |> 
  mutate(
    kruskal = map_dbl(data, kruskal_per_group_NO_weighted),
    kruskal_weighted = map_dbl(data, kruskal_per_group_weighted)
    )

The specific warning message I receive is:
    <warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `kruskal_weighted = map_dbl(data, kruskal_per_group_weighted)`.
Caused by warning in `ft()`:
! rank transformation doesn't take weights into account
---
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
 2. \-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)

Additionally, the p-values for the weighted and non-weighted Kruskal-Wallis tests are different, as shown in the following table:

Is there a way to address this warning and ensure that the rank transformation properly accounts for weights in coin::kruskal_test? Or is there an alternative approach to conducting a weighted Kruskal-Wallis test in R?
Thank you for your assistance.

You could just repeat each observation as many times as the weights, since that's all kruskal_test is doing.

Couldn't the sd be affected on this way and maybe the test?

Absolutely. But that's what you are asking kruskal_test to do, so if you don't want it, you shouldn't be putting weights in the function.  If you have sampling weights instead of frequency weights you could look at survey:::svyranktest
